Nest JS, send big volume of data to SQL Server
I have a problem with my NestJS function; I need to send 300 thousand records to my database, it is not a POST, it is a PATCH.
I have the function to know what data to update, but when uploading the data I found 2 problems:

Sending all the data returned an error, saying that there is too much data to send.
Make a for loop and put my query there, I tried it and it literally took days.

Is there a way to make it more efficient? By a lot or something like that?
for (let i = 0; i < readFile.length; i++) {
    try {
        const aseguradoFile = readFile[i];
        const findAsegurado = usuarios.find(asegurado => {
            const removeGuion = usuarios.fc_nombre_usuario?.replace(/-/g, ' ');
            const removeDobleGuion = removeGuion?.replace(/--/g, ' ');
            const removeDobleEspacio = removeDobleGuion?.replace(/  /g, ' ');
            return removeDobleEspacio.toUpperCase().trim() == String(usuarioFile.Nombre_Completo).toUpperCase().trim();
        });

        usuariosFromFile.push(findUsuario);
/*           const jsonres = {
            ...aseguradoFile,
            ...findAsegurado,
            rfc: calcularRFC(usuarioFile.Nombre, usuarioFile.Paterno, usuarioFile.Materno, findUsuario.fecha_nacimiento)
          } */
          
          const toUpdate = {
            id_usuario: findUsiario.id_usuario,
            rfc: calcularRFC(usuarioFile.Nombre, usuarioFile.Paterno, usuarioFile.Materno, findUsuario.fecha_nacimiento),
            recalculado: rfc !== findUsuario.rfc ? 1 : 0,
            error: 0
          };
          nombres.push(toUpdate);
          //console.log("toUpdate", toUpdate);
          console.log("asegurado::", i);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("Error al actualizar el registro", error);
          const toUpdate = {
id_usuario: findUsiario.id_usuario,
            rfc: null,
            recalculado: 0,
            error: 1
          };
          errors.push(toUpdate);
        };
      };
      const finalArray = [...nombres, ...errors];
      const toUpdate = {
       //id_usuario: () => `CASE id_usuario ${finalArray.map(usuario => `WHEN ${usuario.id_usuario} THEN ${asegurado.id_usuario}`).join(' ')} END`,
      };
      await this.checkNombreExcelRepository
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .update(CheckNombreExcel)
        .set(toUpdate)
        .where('id_usuario IN (:...ids)', { ids: usuarioFromFile.map(usuario => usuario.id_usuario) })
        .execute();
      return {
        total: usuariosFromFile.length,
        message: 'Datos actualizados correctamente',
        code : HttpStatus.OK
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error al actualizar los datos', error);
      throw new HttpException('Error al actualizar los datos', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }    
};

Bulk upload data to the database, my method takes many days

Combine your solutiona? Loop, sending, idk, 1000 records per post?
